# Empirical (Computational) Analysis

Tags: algorithms

how to write a program that display the total running time of a given algorithm based on different situations such as processor speed, input size, processor load, and software environment?

Comment: There exists no such program: even just deciding whether the running time of an input algorithm is finite is an undecidable problem.

Comment: That said, if you have some restrictions on the problem (e.g. it has no recursion and only for-loops), it may be possible.

Comment: In case that "the total running time of a given algorithm based on different situations such as processor speed, input size, processor load, and software environment" is known, and that the question is about how to display them, then this question is off-topic.